# Can you give me a good explanation and an example of a topological linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Can you give me a good explanation and an example of a topological linear space?

Comment: The real line?  It's a vector space, it has a topology, and the vector space operations  are continuous.

Comment: [Look it up on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=topological+linear+space&oq=topological+li&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.5053j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Can you give me another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generalization of a normed linear space. So basically, A TVS is a vector space with a topology on it, which is compatible with the linear structure. Specifically, that means that the addition $+: X \times X \to X$ is continuous w.r.t. the product topology, and so is scalar multiplication $\cdot : \mathbb{F} \times X \to X$.

A reference to learn more is Rudin's Functional Analysis.